# bast way to handle server session reset with ember simple auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am using the ember simple auth. i really like it as it have taken care alot of stuff I need. However I am wondering if there is a good pattern to deal with the situation when the serverside reset the session but `sesssion.isAuthenticated` saying is still valid.

I am using a custom authenticator and authorizer (just FYI). In my usecase I like to able to hook into a modal poping up for signin when serverside have expired. There are a few ways to go about it I suppose but I am wondering if there are better practices out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the server invalidates the session the next time the Ember app makes a request it should receive a 401 response which would trigger automatic invalidation of the Ember Simp,e Auth session. Ember Simple Auth will also invoke the `authorizationFailed` action on the application route when you use the `ApplicationRouteMixin`.